# How much data can Push-OutputBinding handle?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am looking at [this Microsft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal) about `Push-OutputBinding`. In the page linked there is this example:

`Push-OutputBinding -Name outQueue -Value @("output #3", "output #4")`

I also have a PowerShell script that uses `Push-OutputBinding` to write data to an Azure storage table. My question is how much data can I push using a single `Push-OutputBinding`?

Comment: To specify because I am lost here - you are writing the data to the Azure Queue or Azure Table?

Comment: I am writing to a table but I'm really just wondering how much data I can pass with `Push-OutputBinding`

Comment: My question is regarding that there are different storage types that consist of different data stored with different limitations. In terms of queue message can be up to 64KB in size. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-queues-introduction

Comment: Right, but how much data can be passed with `Push-OutputBinding`? For example, I think a row in a storage table can be max 1mb, but how many rows of data could I push? I know I can push 1mb worth of data, but what is the max? Could I push 100gb of data at once?

Comment: The memory limit available for Azure Functions is 1.5 GB to 14 GB depending on the selected Azure Function App Service plan. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale